# How to align the x axis with the chart points in a dc.js ordinal line series chart?

Tags: dc.js

When I try to create an ordinal series chart, the x axis is not aligned with the points in the chart, the ticks positions are shifted to the right of the values.

You can see the problem in this image:

[image]

The first point of the line should be aligned with the x axis's 01 label.

I have tested versions 2.0.2, 2.1.3 and 2.1.8. This is the code:

```js
var chart = dc.seriesChart("#test");
var ndx, runDimension, runGroup;

d3.csv("morley.csv", function(error, experiments) {

  ndx = crossfilter(experiments);
  runDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    var run = +d.Run < 10 ? '0' + d.Run : '' + d.Run;
    return [+d.Expt, run];
  });
  runGroup = runDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return +d.Speed; });

  chart
    .width(768)
    .height(480)
    .chart(function(c) { return dc.lineChart(c).interpolate('cardinal'); })
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .brushOn(false)
    .yAxisLabel("Measured Speed km/s")
    .xAxisLabel("Run")
    .clipPadding(10)
    .elasticY(true)
    .dimension(runDimension)
    .group(runGroup)
    .mouseZoomable(true)
    .seriesAccessor(function(d) {return "Expt: " + d.key[0];})
    .keyAccessor(function(d) {return d.key[1];})
    .valueAccessor(function(d) {return +d.value - 500;})
    .legend(dc.legend().x(350).y(350).itemHeight(13).gap(5).horizontal(1).legendWidth(140).itemWidth(70));
  chart.yAxis().tickFormat(function(d) {return d3.format(',d')(d+299500);});
  chart.margins().left += 40;

  dc.renderAll();

});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Consider adding more about what's going wrong exactly?

Comment: @huwr I updated the image to highlight the problem

Comment: I don't see the issue [in this example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/line.html). I wonder if it is specifically a problem with using ordinal scales with the line chart, which is an uncommon thing to do.

Comment: Actually the github issue explains it better than that previous question, but it's the same solution. https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/662

Comment: @Gordon the problem is when using ordinal scales in a composite or series chart. Thank you.